# Why does adding my Sql UPDATE break my loop?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have the following code which, without the escaped SQL statement, is working fine - it iterates over the full set of returns from a previous SELECT query printing the ID,  detected language (from bingtranslate) and text.

```
for row in c:
  lang=bingtranslate(row[0])
  tweetid = row[1]
  print tweetid, lang, row[0]
  #c.execute('UPDATE tweet SET iso_language_code=? WHERE id=?',(lang, tweetid))
```

When I unescape the UPDATE call, it loops once, and then stops.

What gives?  No error reported.  I'm sure it's something simple but I just can't crack it...

Comment: I'm not a python guy but does executing a query against your results collection `c` cause that collection to be reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Python, so I try to explain what I do in C#.
You're executing a Command using same object of a DataReader (`c` in python), so you have a reset and so the strange behaviour.
In my opinion you don't need to copy rows in another object, but only create a new Command object (empty) and use that to execute your query taking params from `c`.
Correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Answer (score 4):

I think the call to `execute` alters the state of `c`, so that on the next iteration the loop ends.

Comment: ah, OK - so I should copy c into another list[] and then iterate over that?  with nearly 1 million rows that's going to hurt, but at least it will work...

Comment: @Toby: I don't know Python, so I try to explain what I do in C#. You're executing a Command using same object of a DataReader, so you have a reset and so the strange behaviour. In my opinion you don't need to copy rows in another object, but only create a new Command object (empty) and use that to execute your query taking params from `c`. Correct me if I'm wrong, please.